# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal

Tags: android, double

Hi I'm taking a value from edittext and converting displaying that value in other text but getting run time error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "".at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal. In my setAdapter its taking only franheit that means only todetails. I didn't understand where the bug is

```
public class UniqueConverter extends Fragment {

    private Spinner fromDetails, toDetails;
    private EditText fromInput, toInput;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_uniquelayout, container, false);
onInitVies(view);
        int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        String ifrom,rto;
        Double inp;
        double out = 0;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                setAdapter(temperatureform, "Celsius", "Fahrenheit");
                ifrom = (String) fromDetails.getSelectedItem();
                rto = (String) toDetails.getSelectedItem();
                inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
                TemperatureConverter con = new TemperatureConverter();
                TemperatureConverter.Units fromUnit = TemperatureConverter.Units.fromString(ifrom);
                TemperatureConverter.Units toUnit = TemperatureConverter.Units.fromString(rto);
                out = con.TemperatureConvert(fromUnit,toUnit,inp);
                break;
            case 1:
                setAdapter(weightform, "Kilograms", "Grams");
                ifrom = (String) fromDetails.getSelectedItem();
                rto = (String) toDetails.getSelectedItem();
                inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
                WeightConverter converter = new WeightConverter();
                WeightConverter.Inus fromInus = WeightConverter.Inus.fromString(ifrom);
                WeightConverter.Inus toInus = WeightConverter.Inus.fromString(rto);
                out = converter.WeightConvert(fromInus, toInus, inp);
                break;

  final double finalOut = out;
        fromInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    if (!fromInput.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    {
                        toInput.setText(String.valueOf(finalOut));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toInput.setText("");
                    }

                }
            });


            return view;

    }


    private void setAdapter(String[] spinnerItems, String fromDefaultText, String toDefaultText) {
        fromDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, fromDefaultText));
        toDetails.setAdapter(new CustomSpinnerAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.spinner_item, spinnerItems, toDefaultText));
    }

    private void onInitVies(View view) {
        fromDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
        toDetails = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);

        fromInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.fromInput);
        toInput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.toInput);
    }
```

logcat:

```
 Process: com.cloudicalabs.converters, PID: 8063
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:338)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.cloudicalabs.converters.fragments.UniqueConverter.onCreateView(UniqueConverter.java:74)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
03-16 03:47:54.078 8063-8063/com.cloudicalabs.converters E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
```

Comment: can you please post your error line 74 @sun

Comment: If your string is empty or null than you will get NumberFormateExaception error.So before converting string to float or double you have check that your string is empty or not.

Comment: inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString()); this is my error line

Comment: You get an empty string in `fromInput.getText().toString(); ` which can not converted to a double

Comment: Why are you using `Double` and `double` ?

Comment: one for taking input and another displays input

Comment: use `Float inp= Float.parseFloat(fromInput.getText().toString());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
   inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   inp = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try replacing this line**

```
inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
```

**with**

```
inp = Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString());
```

Comment: a problem occur my setAdapter taking only todetails means it taking faranheit while debugging.

Comment: my spinners taking same value

Comment: where did you initialize those spinners ?

Comment: initialized in onInitVies method, please check in the code

Comment: Have you been released with `NumberFormatException` and another issue raised or still showing the same error ??

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the variable or resource from which you want to get value is null and so it is saying that " " is not double. If you are getting value from `fromInput.getText().toString()` then fromInput has no value and thus null can't be cast to double.

Comment: he is doing it in initViews() function; he would have got NPE its basics :) @Parsania Hardik

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(fromInput.getText())
    {
      String value=null;
        try {
            value=String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(fromInput.getText().toString()));
            toInput.setText(value);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            toInput.setText("");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        toInput.setText("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before doing this

```
inp = Double.valueOf(fromInput.getText().toString());
```

check whether the value from the fromInput text is having "" (empty -i.e holding nothing: say like .length == 0) then u shouldn't parse it; instead notify user to enter some value. **also put it in try catch**.